# Checking discord command parameters

Tags: python, discord.py

I dont have much to say, im trying to make an bot for discord using python.

The command is when I do

```
+permissions <user>
```

It shows a list of the user's permissions

Heres the problem:
[image: COMMAND]

So, the permission im starting with is "Administrator"

And depending if the user has the permission it shows an unique message saying if he has the permission or not

As you see in here

```
if ctx.message.user.server_permissions.administrator == True:
    embed.add_field(name="Administrator", value=":white_ckeck_mark: Permission Granted!", inline=True)
if ctx.message.user.server_permissions.administrator == False:    
    embed.add_field(name="Administrator", value=":x: Permission Denied!", inline=True)
```

But it shows the error saying that I didnt inputed an argument (user)

[image: ERROR ON DISCORD]

**ALL CODE**

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def permissions(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    embed = discord.Embed(name="USER_PERMISSIONS", description="------------------------------------------------------", color=0x0099ff)
    embed.set_author(name="USER_PERMISSIONS: {}'s Permissions".format(user.name))
if ctx.message.user.server_permissions.administrator == True:
    embed.add_field(name="Administrator", value=":white_ckeck_mark: Permission Granted!", inline=True)
if ctx.message.user.server_permissions.administrator == False:    
    embed.add_field(name="Administrator", value=":x: Permission Denied!", inline=True)
if ctx.message.user.server_permissions.view_audit_logs == True:
    embed.add_field(name="View Audit Logs", value=":white_ckeck_mark: Permission Granted!", inline=True)
if ctx.message.user.server_permissions.view_audit_logs == False:
    embed.add_field(name="View Audit Logs", value=":x: Permission Denied!", inline=True)
embed.set_thumbnail(url=user.avatar_url)
embed.set_footer(text="Requested by {}".format(author), icon_url=author.avatar_url)
await bot.say(embed=embed)
```

Comment: please, do not post your code as image, it is a text -- post it like a text

Comment: Please post code as code-formatted text, screenshots are difficult to read and use.

Comment: just added all code sorry. Please Refresh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working code

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def permissions(ctx, user: discord.Member):
  embed = discord.Embed(name="USER_PERMISSIONS", description="------------------------------------------------------", color=0x0099ff)
  embed.set_author(name="USER_PERMISSIONS: {}'s Permissions".format(user.name))
  if user.server_permissions.administrator == True:
    embed.add_field(name="Administrator", value=":white_check_mark:  Permission Granted!", inline=True)
  if user.server_permissions.administrator == False:    
    embed.add_field(name="Administrator", value=":x: Permission Denied!", inline=True)
  if user.server_permissions.view_audit_logs == True:
    embed.add_field(name="View Audit Logs", value=":white_check_mark:  Permission Granted!", inline=True)
  if user.server_permissions.view_audit_logs == False:
    embed.add_field(name="View Audit Logs", value=":x: Permission Denied!", inline=True)
  embed.set_thumbnail(url=user.avatar_url)
  embed.set_footer(text="Requested by {}".format(ctx.message.author), icon_url=ctx.message.author.avatar_url)
  await bot.say(embed=embed)
```

A couple of things, first off you don't need to use `ctx.message.user.server_permissions` if you've already initialised what the user is so just use `user.server_permissions` as `ctx.message` has no attribute called "user"

Secondly author is not defined, use `ctx.author` to display who sent the message

And lastly you misspelt `:white_check_mark:`

Hopefully this helped!

[image: This is how it all looks in the end]